# The function works in two scenarios

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

```
def is_valid_shelf_life(date):
    try:
        shelf_life = datetime.strptime(date, "%d.%m.%y")
    except(TypeError, ValueError):
        return True
    return False


@db.message_handler(is_valid_shelf_life, state=ProductAddingStatesGroup.shelf_life)
async def check_shelf_life(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Дата введена не корректно!")
```

the `check_shelf_life` function should work when the date is entered incorrectly, but in my case when I enter the correct date the check still fails.

I tried to swap True and False in the `is_valid_shelf_life` function, but in this case correct and invalid data passed through.

Comment: The post needs more explanation about the goal of the code and the format of the input date examples.

Comment: I write a telegram bot and before I save the date I check it, if the date is entered incorrectly the check_shelf_life handler is called, if it is correct I save it in the state machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to enter `date.text`, not just the `date`

Answer (score 0):

1. Change True and False.
2. Your `"%d.%m.%y"` is waiting for `16.11.23`. You cant use `2023`. If you want to use full year then use `%Y`.

Look at [strptime format codes in docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

```py
def is_valid_shelf_life(date):
    try:
        shelf_life = datetime.strptime(date, "%d.%m.%y")
    except(TypeError, ValueError):
        return False
    return True

is_valid_shelf_life("16.11.23") # True
is_valid_shelf_life("16.11.2023") # False
is_valid_shelf_life("16.13.23") # Fasle
```

Comment: I just need it to be True when the date is entered incorrectly to catch an error.

Comment: @Kazak ok, then just fix strptime format i guess? give me example input of date